# write hebrew to excel with df.to_csv() and 'utf-8' present weird chars

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, character-encoding, hebrew

I have a dataframe with words in Hebrew.
I am using `df.to_csv(encoding='utf-8')` to write it but the words are not presented good:

[image]

When open it in TextEdit, I see the Hebrew properly.
I am using Mac with Python3 and Microsoft Excel 16.16.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is in the software you use to view the file. Make sure the encoding is not set to ASCII

Comment: @DeepSpace How to do it with excel 16.16 in Mac? couldn't find it

Comment: Not related to SO: https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1366665/set-character-encoding-in-mac-os-and-microsoft-excel?noredirect=1#comment2055604_1366665

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with your file, since you did not share the file.  But in Windows Excel, when you import a csv file, there is an option to choose the source data encoding.  Does that not exist in Mac Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld no, and I also couldn't change it in Save As

Comment: What happens when you select `Data/From Text`?  The text import wizard should open, and that should have an option to specify `File Origin`, even on the MAC.  Note that there is a difference betweein **import**ing and **open**ing a file

Comment: import using Data->Get External data and choosing UTF-8 worked

Comment: And that was the answer given in the duplicate of your message first posted in superuser.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False ,encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```